# How do we know relativistic mass also includes potential energy?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, potential-energy, mass-energy

From Special Relativity it is shown that relativistic mass increases with kinetic energy, but how do we know potential energy is also part of relativistic mass? Is this a derived conclusion, or should it be treated as a first principle whose correctness is only verified by experiments (for example the measured mass of composite particles)?

Comment: From your first statement, mass increases with KE, I guess you are refering to relativistic mass instead of rest mass?

Comment: More on [potential energy in SR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potential-energy+special-relativity).

Comment: It is derived. Very few first principles exist in physics and this definitely is not one of them.  Examples of the first principles include the Least Action Principle, general covariance (in general relativity), the uniformity and homogeneity of spacetime (in special relativity), U(1) symmetry in electromagnetism. Most, if not all of them simply reflect some symmetry that the nature has been observed to obey. Some of them also have limits. For example, the uniformity of apcetime is broken globally by general covariance (massive bodies curve spacetime), weak interactions violate flavor, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> How do we know mass also includes potential energy?

Mass is connected to potential energy,

> From Special Relativity it is shown that mass increases with kinetic energy,

This is the relativistic mass that increases with with kinetic energy, i.e. the mass equivalent in Newton's $F=ma$

> but how do we know potential energy is also part of mass?

It is not. In Newtonian physics which macroscopic bodies obey,  mass is an additive quantity, and is accurate to very great accuracy, that is why[Archimedes principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle) works.  One has to go to nuclear and elementary particle sizes to find a connection between mass , energy and potential energy, in the realm of [quantum mechanics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics)

Mass at this level is an invariant to the Lorentz transformations , the length of the [four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) which describes a system, and there potential energy enters in the calculations.

[A hydrogen atom](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html) is lighter in mass than an (electron +  proton), because the electron falling to the ground state of the potential well releases a photon, and the photon four vector takes away energy, which is missing in the summation of the four vectors of the bound electrons and protons, making the atom with smaller invariant mass than the sum of its parts.

> (for example the measured mass of composite particles)?

take the deuteron, so as to have some numbers in kg,The free proton and neutron masses  add up to $3.3474 * 10^{-27}$kg, the mass of the deuteron is $3.3435 * 10^{-27}$kg .

It is thinking in terms of addition of the four vectors that will give the correct algebra of special relativity and the relation of masses to binding energy/potentials.

Edit after comment:

As Safesphere's comment indicates and [this link studies](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1979Ap%26SS..65..397V), the case of general relativity, the gravitational potential and mass energy becomes more complicated.

The [Newtonian case is here,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy#Negative_mass_component) again by Safesphere.

He gives a good precis in his comment:

> this is gravitational binding energy that creates a mass defect similar to your electromagnetic example. The difference is that the electromagnetic field is created by charges, not masses, so the mass defect cannot be absorbed by the field, but must be emitted as a photon. In contrast, gravity is created by masses, so the mass defect of the binding energy is simply absorbed by the field itself. .. The effect in GR is only stronger

Comment: In addition to quantum mechanics where fields are strong compared to the classical physics, the mass defect can also be found in general relativity where fields are also strong. The mass-energy of a falling body approaches zero as the body approaches the event horizon of a black hole. This mass-energy is gradually transferred to increase the potential energy of the gravitational field of the black hole. The same is true in the Newtonian gravity limit, but the mass defect is just too small to measure per $E=mc^2". So the potential energy always is a part of the mass, just normally a small one.

Comment: @safesphere can you give a link with more mathematical information?

Comment: @annav you say that when a nucleus and an electron become bound, the electron releases a photon. Now with the deuteron, when the proton and neutron become bound, does any of them release a photon too or how do they release the energy?

Comment: Anna, this is gravitational binding energy that creates a mass defect similar to your electromagnetic example. The difference is that the electromagnetic field is created by charges, not masses, so the mass defect cannot be absorbed by the field, but must be emitted as a photon. In contrast, gravity is created by masses, so the mass defect of the binding energy is simply absorbed by the field itself. Here is the Newtonian limit math: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy#Negative_mass_component - The effect in GR is only stronger, but a link is hard to find.

Comment: @safesphere  thanks. I found a paper for gr , see my edit for link. I will include your comment. If you post an answer, I will  edit it out and refer to it.